# Controller not receiving data sent by AJAX Request. ASP.NET CORE MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

`Hi everyone I am having an issue with my colleague assignment if someone could please help me. This is ASP.NET Core MVC.
I have an API Controller to edit the group of students. This API Receives a GroupViewModel as parameter to do the update. The model received is valid but the variables in it are null.
At the client-side when I check the request being sent, it does have data.
I appreciate your insights!

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbQ59.png)
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3oIC.png)
[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlGoM.png)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... What happens if you don't use `JSON.stringify` before sending the data?  It's strange to me to send a string instead of simply sending the object.

Comment: In your Controller, include ([FromBody] GroupViewModel model).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

Option 1:Try to remove  JSON.stringify and contentType:

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: '/Enrollment/EditGroup',
     data: updatedGroup,
     success: function (r) {
             console.log("RESULT", r);
              },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
    }
 });
```

result:

[image]

Option 2:Add `[FromBody]` like:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult EditGroup([FromBody]GroupViewModel _data)
{
   //do your staff
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Josué Ramírez, any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know?